# ACR122U Answer D5 41 13 90 00 to mifare's read command

Tags: nfc, mifare, acr122

I have problem with use **direct** command for mifare 1k via ACR122U. I use original SDK for Windows (including for delphi), and I sent these commands in one session:
FF 00 00 00 means pseudo-apdu. It is used to send direct commands to tag or to device (ACR).

```
<< FF 00 00 00 02 D4 02 // GET FIRMWARE
>> D5 03 32 01 06 07 90 00 

<< FF 00 00 00 03 D4 12 24 // SET PARAMETERS (I want to disable not suported ISO 14443-4)
// (I also tried D2 12 14 without success)
>> D5 13 90 00 

<< FF 00 00 00 0F D4 40 01 60 00 FF FF FF FF FF FF xx xx xx xx // auth with key A (tag UID hidden) 
>> D5 41 00 90 00 // OK 

<< FF 00 00 00 05 D4 40 01 30 00 // direct mifare read (30) block 00 
>> D5 41 13 90 00  // ERROR 13 (incorrect value of PCB or PFB, invalid or unexpected received frame, NAD or DID incoherence, bad length of received RF frame).
```

I cannot read any card (i have three). All cards can be read with command FF B0 00 00 10...

Can you please tell me, what command(s) shall be sent before and after authentification to correctly communicate with the card? Please also send links to specification of commands Read register (D4 06) and write register (D4 08). I don't know what means register "63 05" (D4 06 63 05) for example.

BTW. What mean abbreviations (in context): NAD, DID, PFB, PCB?

Comment: NAD = Node Address Byte, PCB = Protocol Control Byte.

Comment: Did you try authenticating other block rather than 00? Try authenticating and reading 04 block?

Comment: Yes. I tried also 04 and 08 and failed. Auth: OK, Reading: failed.